# How to reload datatable using ajax by passing parameter in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am new in using ajax, the topic I have a doubt since I have only used it to obtain data and not to filter with a DOM element external to the table.

The thing is that I bring 5 options in button form with the following script:

```js
<script>
$('button').on('click',function(){
   //const filter_status = $(this).val();
   $(".iq-bg-success").removeClass("iq-bg-success");
   $(this).addClass("iq-bg-success");
});
</script>
```

[image]

This script allows me to activate the button from which I want to get the ID to send it with the ajax request and update the table without reloading the data according to the filter.

Currently I am not running the post method so I have my base script to load data into the datable.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        
        $('button').on('click',function(){
            //const filter_status = $(this).val();
            $(".iq-bg-success").removeClass("iq-bg-success");
            $(this).addClass("iq-bg-success");
        });

        $('#tabla').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "lead/list",
                dataSrc: "data",
                type: "GET"
            },
            language: {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'source.name', defaultContent: '-' },
                { data: 'request_date' },
                { data: 'contact.fullName' },
                { data: 'contact.email', visible: false },
                { data: 'contact.score',render(data){
                    if ( data >=0 && data<=3 ) {
                        return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger text-center">'+ data +'</span>';
                    }else if( data >=4 && data<= 6 ){
                        return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning text-white text-center">'+ data +'</sapn>';
                    }else{
                        return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success text-center">'+ data +'</span>';
                    }
                }},
                { data: 'seller', render(data){
                    if (data == '') {
                        return '-';
                    }else{
                        return data;
                    }
                } },
                { data: 'solicitudes.status.name' },
                { data: 'btn', ordering: false, searching: false}
            ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I managed to make it work in part, but I have the problem that when I start the page no data appears because I am required to press a button to display data.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $('button').on('click',function(){
            const filter_status = $(this).val();
            $(".iq-bg-success").removeClass("iq-bg-success");
            $(this).addClass("iq-bg-success");
            load_datatable_filter(filter_status);
        });

        function load_datatable_filter(filter_status){
            console.log(filter_status);
            $('#tabla').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "lead/list",
                    //dataSrc: "data",
                    data: {'id': filter_status},
                    type: "GET"
                },
                language: {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'source.name', defaultContent: '-' },
                    { data: 'request_date' },
                    { data: 'contact.fullName' },
                    { data: 'contact.email', visible: false },
                    { data: 'contact.score',render(data){
                        if ( data >=0 && data<=3 ) {
                            return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger text-center">'+ data +'</span>';
                        }else if( data >=4 && data<= 6 ){
                            return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning text-white text-center">'+ data +'</sapn>';
                        }else{
                            return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success text-center">'+ data +'</span>';
                        }
                    }},
                    { data: 'seller', render(data){
                        if (data == '') {
                            return '-';
                        }else{
                            return data;
                        }
                    } },
                    { data: 'solicitudes.status.name' },
                    { data: 'btn', ordering: false, searching: false}
                ],
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

On the other hand when I select 1 button and then select the next one it throws me an error alert.

[image]

Comment: To avoid the error message shown in your last picture, please read this **[Warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3)**

Comment: Yeah If you have already fixed it, put ```destroy: true``` But I have a problem that when I select another button the hidden column I have is shown shortly so that they can filter by mail.